# What files from VB6 are redistributable?

Tags: vb6

I have searched for a list of VB6 files that are redistributable, but did not find one. Can anyone point me to such a list? I specifically need to verify that tabctl32.ocx is redistributable. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a file on the Visual Studio 6.0 setup disk that contains a list of redistributable components - \Disk1\common\redist\redist.txt

In short, it confirms that you can redistribute tabctl32.ocx.

From the VB6 EULA:

> 4.1.2 Redistributable Code-Extended Use. Visual Basic, Visual C++, Visual J++, and Visual Studio. If this EULA accompanies any of the Microsoft products listed in the heading of this subsection, you may permit your end users to reproduce and distribute the object code form of certain portions of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT (as listed in REDIST.TXT as "Extended Use Redistributable Code") only in conjunction with and part of a Licensed Product and/or Web page that adds significant and primary functionality to the Extended Use Redistributable Code.

The "Extended Use" section of REDIST.TXT includes tabctl32.ocx.

Answer (score 3):

Here's [Microsoft's list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) of the controls that are supported on Vista and Windows 7. Some are distributed with Windows, and some you have to distribute yourself - listed under *Supported Runtime Files to Distribute with Your Application*.

`tabctl32.ocx` is supported, but you have to distribute it yourself. I think that's confirmation that you are legally allowed to distribute it.

(Edit: See also [Controls shipped in Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194784))